# Caching function values in HashMap

Tags: scala, types

Using Scala 2.13.5, I am trying to implement a table that stores values of a certain simple kind. (What I'm really interested in is more hairy, but the simple version illustrates my problem.)

```
import scala.collection.immutable.HashMap

class ListMap[K] private[ListMap] (hm: HashMap[K, List[K]]) {
  
  def put[V1 <: K, V2 <: List[K]](k: V1, x: V2
                                 )(implicit ev: V2 =:= List[V1]):
      ListMap[K] = {
    new ListMap[K](hm + ((k -> x)))
  }

  def get[V1 <: K](x: V1): Option[List[V1]] = hm.get(x)

}

object ListMap {
  def make[K] = new ListMap[K](new HashMap[K, List[K]]())
}
```

The idea is that you might have a `ListMap[Any]` with entries such as `3 -> List(2,2)` and `"abc" -> List("foo", "bar")`. The stored value is a list of objects of the same type as the key.

The code does not compile. The error message is

```
...error: type mismatch;
 found   : Option[List[K]]
 required: Option[List[V1]]
  def get[V1 <: K](x: V1): Option[List[V1]] = hm.get(x)
```

Changing the definition of `get` so its return type is `Option[List[K]]` "solves" the problem.
However, the `put` function actually guarantees the stronger property, that the value stored for a given `x` of type `V1` is a `List[V1]`.  I've beat my head against this problem long enough that I'm convinced it is just beyond the capabilities of the Scala type system. Am I right? Is there a way to tell the type system: Believe me, the type of the value is `List[V1]`? I would be willing to do a redundant test on the found list to verify that each of its elements satisfies some predicate if I knew how to translate that into the type declaration I want.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to tell the type system: Believe me, the type of the value is `List[V1]`?

There is an escape hatch, if you're absolutely sure:

```scala
hm.get(x).asInstanceOf[Option[List[V1]]]
```

Note that `asInstanceOf` is generally frowned on (with good reason), but there are times where the escape hatch is needed.